# Block direct access to resources depending on referer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|png|css|js)$ - [NC,F]
```

Here it blocks, but in normal loading the files are not able to load, only html contents are loaded, resources not appearing in page. Like images,css, js etc.

Comment: What do you mean by `in normal load` ?

Comment: i just added the above code in my .htaccess file , but when my page got loaded it blocked all the images and css . How to solve this. I need to restrict only the direct access.